# Is there a way to enable snapchat like swipe navigation using reactnavigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I see some tutorials using react-native-swiper

https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/implement-snapchat-like-swipe-navigation-declaratively-in-react-native-309e71229c89

And another navigation library

https://github.com/AZZB/react-native-swipe-navigation

But is there a way to do this kind of navigation using react-navigation which I have already installed and implemented in my app?

I'd like to avoid adding another navigation implementation to my project if possible.  Ideally It would be similar to a tabnavigator but would be activated by swipes and would have a transparent tab background.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old but for those to come. React navigation v3 has is capable of this. Use {materialTopTabNavigator} and make sure handleGestures is set to true in the navigationOptions